# Photoshop style anti aliasing style in css

Tags: css, fonts, antialiasing

I'm in the process of setting up a stylesheet for a PSD mockup we have of a new website. Most of the text in the mockup uses the 'sharp' anti aliasing method from photoshop.

What's the best way to re-create these kind of photoshop anti aliasing methods? Setting different font-weights seem way off..

Btw, the font is Arial so no funny @font-face stuff going on here

Comment: I'd pre-render the text as an image, but this is body text which is likely to be changed often, and obviously we don't want to use images for everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple alternative is a [text-shadow](http://slides.html5rocks.com/#css-shadow), which is a css3 property:

```
#foo {
    /* text-shadow: [color] [horizontal offset] [vertical offset] [blur] */
    text-shadow: #fff 0 1px 0;
}
```

Play around with the settings; you can make a very sharp end edgy looking font smooth, by experimenting with different colors and blur values.

Comment: Obviously this isn't a silver bullet, but I must say the effect is quite pleasing on the eye.

Answer (score 1):

The `font-smooth` CSS3 property may be useful:

```
font-smooth: auto | never | always | <absolute-size> | length | initial | inherit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script-based library ([cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) comes to mind) to customize anti-aliasing and other text rendering effects. Note that most (if not all) such solutions are only appropriate for headers and whatnot, not the full body text.

Answer (score -1):

Because you website is going to be shown in multiple browsers in multiple OS's, there is no way to get a consistent font display. I think it is down to the OS with regards to font smoothing.

If you require it, render the portions as an image or use Cufon or sIFR.

What I have also done in the past, if the font is a little rough, add a subtle CSS3 `text-shadow` which makes it look much smoother.